# openxml removing large bookmarks

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml

I'm currently working on a OpenXML project with ASP.NET and C#, we need to inject into and hide certain sections of a Word document.  I'm doing this with Bookmarks.  For injection, i'm fine, I'm able to locate the Bookmark Start and End, I'm able to inject the text I want to in those bookmarks.  For hiding bookmarks I'm running into some issues.

For hiding paragraphs for example, I'm able to remove them, using the bookmarkStart.Remove() and bookmarkEnd.Remove(), however the bookmarks leave the space where they were, I would like to have the line they were on also deleted.  Otherwise it leaves a blank line there.

Also for paragraphs, if I need to hide multiple, I bookmark the entire block but when I remove the bookmark just the 1st paragraph goes, others remain.  I had Word display all characters and it looks like the bookmark removes until the 1st paragraph end after that it does not work, even though the entire group of paragraphs are bookmarked together.

Is there a way to get around this, maybe I shouldn't be using bookmarks to remove groups of text?  Otherwise if bookmarks are the way to go, how do I get them to remove the lines they were on and to span more than one paragraph and delete.

the reason I was using bookmarks was the users want to see them in the word doc, they want to be able to mark sections themselves, and then the application will pick it up and hide sections based on answers provided.

Below is an example of the generated xml:

```html
  <w:p w:rsidR="002C4A92" w:rsidRDefault="002C4A92">
    <w:pPr>
  ...
    </w:pPr>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:name="SWCBM" w:id="11" />
    <w:r>
  ...
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
  ...
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="0087646D">
  ...
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
  ...
    </w:r>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="11" />
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="002C4A92" w:rsidRDefault="002C4A92">
    <w:pPr>
   ...
    </w:pPr>
  </w:p>
```

Comment: I prefer `Rich Text Content Controls` over Bookmarks for solving these kind of problems. In addition I think using ContentControls could also solve your problem with removing, as I won't leave blank lines there.

Comment: Could you copy / past the xml of your file ? (rename your file .zip and open the words/document.xml and look for your code). It's the simplest way to determine how manipulate the xml

Comment: @MaximePorté I've updated my question with a sample of the xml

Comment: @DavidLeitner If I switch to Rich Text content Controls can I also use openxml to loop through and locate them, hiding them as needed?  Can they span more than one paragraph?

Comment: @Paritosh Yes you can do all these things

Comment: @DavidLeitner is possible, could you provide a sample of how to locate it, by id?  I'm searching but having trouble finding how to locate a Rich Text control in the document.

Comment: @Parithos: start a new question, as this is a new topic.

Comment: @DavidLeitner done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880857/navigating-rich-text-control-in-openxml