# Navigating Rich Text Control in OpenXml

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml

I'm working with OpenXml and C#, I'm was using bookmarks but now might be switching over to Rich Text Controls. I was able to locate and work with the bookmarks, but i'm having some issues locating the Rich Text Controls.  I'm trying the below:

```
IEnumerable<SdtBlock> contentControlsDoc = null;
((MainDocumentPart)section).Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>();
foreach (var contentControl in contentControlsDoc)
{
}
```

I'm able to get 1 control, but sometimes I have a Rich Text Control within another, is there anyway to get them all together from the document.  Also is there a way to locate them by the Title or Tag id I gave them in Word?

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
document.Controls.OfType<RichTextContentControl>().FirstOrDefault(rtcc => rtcc.ID = id);
```

to access a RichTextContenControl by Id.

Comment: what type is document?  When I do ((MainDocumentPart)section).Document. I don't get Controls same when I try ((MainDocumentPart)section).Document.Body. neither has a Controls property.

Comment: sorry for the late answer: document in my case is the ThisDocument from your VSTO project. ThisDocument inherits from DocumentBase (Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word) which has the property Controls.

Comment: maybe because I was using OpenXML the .Controls never came up for me, but I ended up using your suggestion of using Rich Text Controls over bookmarks to hide/show blocks and it's working great.